# Array converted to object in post request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post, axios

I have an array of objects.  I would like to send these as data in a post request, using axios:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    responseType: 'json'
})

const options = {
    data: [{ title: 'test1' }, { title: 'test2' }, { title: 'test3' }]
}

axios.post(route, null, options)
```

However, when I parse the data on the server, it is converted from an array to an object.  When I look at the request payload in Chrome developer tools, the data is instead being sent as:

```
{
    0: { title: 'test1' },
    1: { title: 'test2' },
    2: { title: 'test3' }
}
```

So it appears that the array gets converted to object format before it is sent.  Is this the expected behaviour?  (A property on an object that is an array does not get converted in this fashion.)  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your **data** in the **second argument** of `axios.post`. Like this

```
axios
  .post('example.com', [{
    title: 'test1'
  }, {
    title: 'test2'
  }, {
    title: 'test3'
  }]);
```

Also make sure you check out their [README](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) for more examples